# Get record with a field egal to a specific value else with null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want in SQL : if a field is equal to a specific value, I want this record if not I want the record with this field equal to null.

I can try to that:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM TABLE1 WHERE (COL2 = MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE OR COL2 IS NULL) AND COL3 = '42'
AND COL1 = 3
```

But, what is the result returned? The smallest id? Or it is not specified?

Comment: So am I correct: you want all the rows to appear, but if a particular row has a particular value, you want a column to be replaced by "null"? If so, yes, COALESCE is definitely wrong. Can you give us a little sample data?

Comment: It's not specified. `TOP` without `ORDER BY` will give you an arbitrary result. If you want a specific row to be chosen, use `ORDER BY`.

Comment: It's not possible that this condition: `WHERE COL2 = '42' AND COL1 = 3` would give you a result with `COL2` NULL

Comment: As an aside `COALESCE(MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE, COL2)` will always return the value for `MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE` provided `MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE` is not null which is why your first query didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is the real question:

> > If a field is equal to a specific value, I want this record if not I want the record with this field equal to null.

You can do this as:

```
SELECT TOP 1 COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM TABLE1
WHERE (COL2 = MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE or COL2 IS NULL) AND
      COL3 = '42' AND COL1 = 3
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN COL2 = MY_SPECIFIC_VALUE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END);
```